# Remove from Queue

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

```
public E remove() {
    if(top!=null){
        E item = top.data;
        top=top.next;
        return item;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Trying to remove Node from queue without using java.util.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes you are on the right track. Is that the only question?

Comment: Remember - you can always look at the Java source code and see how they implemented things - the source comes with the JDK in src.zip (usually).

Comment: @Kon actually could you kinda explain to me what all this method does.  Like I know that it removes a node but could you dumb it down for me?

Comment: @user3277779 The method looks at the queue, and if it has a `top` element, it will make the NEXT element the `top` element, then return the previous top element to the caller.